# Google Charts API with ASP.NET WebForms - writing the DataTables

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, google-visualization

I am creating some charts in my ASP.NET WebForms aplication and for create the charts in my application, and for the chart's data, I have to write strings for the datatables (in javascript) like:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pencils');
data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
data.addColumn('string', 'text1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sold Pens');
data.addColumn('string', 'title2');
data.addColumn('string', 'text2');
data.addRows([
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 30000, null, null, 40645, null, null],
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,2), 14045, null, null, 20374, null, null],
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,3), 55022, null, null, 50766, null, null],
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,4), 75284, null, null, 14334, 'Out of Stock', 'Ran out of stock on pens at 4pm'],
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,5), 41476, 'Bought Pens', 'Bought 200k pens', 66467, null, null],
  [new Date(2008, 1 ,6), 33322, null, null, 39463, null, null]
]);
```

I'm using SqlDataReaders to do this, creating this dirty code:

```
string jsGraph = "";
jsGraph += "data.addRows([";
            while (dsChartsData.Read())
            {
                var d = (DateTime)dsChartsData["dateColumn"];
                jsGraph += "[new Date(" + d.Year.ToString() + ", " + d.Month.ToString() + ", " + d.Day.ToString() + "), " + dsChartsData["value1"].ToString() + ", null, null, " + dsChartsData["value3"].ToString() + ", null, null],";
            }
jsGraph += "]);"
```

Is there any way to do this more maintainable, with a clean code and easy to debug? (javascript in .cs files is a big mess in my code, million of concatenations and stuff)

*Obs: Currently I'm using webForms but if some of you have a great advantage doing this with MVC, please tell me, maybe I can create pages in MVC only to renderize charts (after learning that, of course).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are **missing** the separation comma `,` from your javascript array...

Secondly, why so much concatenations? Why not a public variable and call it from javascript?

like:

```
public string graphData = "";
```

In your method:

```
StringBuilder jsGraph = new StringBuilder();
jsGraph.AppendLine("[");

while (dsChartsData.Read())
{
    var d = (DateTime)dsChartsData["dateColumn"];
    jsGraph.AppendLine("[new Date(" + d.Year.ToString() + ", " + d.Month.ToString() + ", " + d.Day.ToString() + "), " + dsChartsData["value1"].ToString() + ", null, null, " + dsChartsData["value3"].ToString() + ", null, null],");
}
jsGraph.AppendLine("]");

graphData = jsGraph.ToString();
```

and in your Javascript:

```
var graphData = <%= graphData %>;
...    
data.addRows(graphData);
```

BTW, your big concatenation should be written as:

```
jsGraph.AppendFormat(
            "[new Date({0:yyyy, M, d}), {1}, null, null, {2}, null, null],", 
              (DateTime)dsChartsData["dateColumn"], 
              dsChartsData["value1"],
              dsChartsData["value3"]);
```

witch can be much easier to read.